# How to use special onscroll effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I'm a pretty basic coder. I took one Web Design class my sopohmore year in HS and now I'm a junior just trying to make a personal website for college and stuff.

One of these things is use animations. I want to make my pictures flip or slide in on scroll and i found the AOS library while looking online.

http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

I tried learning, but GitHub is really confusing me as are Bower and Npn or whatever they are. I want to be able to use the AOS library commands on my site, but I barely know a thing about javascript as all I really ever learned was HTML and CSS. I tried my best to follow this video even though I use Windows since it's generally the same idea:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XriUcr-QT0

(Skip to 0:34) I downloaded the AOS zip from github and when I tried to grab the CSS and JS sheets or plugin things he calls them, I can't even find the folder. I tried linking the sheets as the AOS library website said at the bottom, with the CSS link rel in the head and javascript link in the body, but when i try to initiate the use of an AOS, the command looks liek this:

With the data-aos part in normal text unlike when you call upon an id or class. Where is the dist folder as the video states and how do I properly link and use these commands as provided in the AOS library? Also, do I need to use and understand whatever yarn and Bower are for my small personal website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is pretty simple, you can use my example here...

https://jsfiddle.net/54cvqLy8/2/

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
</head>
<body style="float:left;width:50%">
<div class ="big-div" data-aos="fade-in">Hello!</div>
<div class ="big-div" data-aos="fade-right">Goodbye!</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init({
                easing: 'ease-out-back',
                duration: 2000 // this is the time the transistion takes to complete
            });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the style to be added

```
.big-div {
  float:left;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  heigth:330px;
  padding-top:200px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:yellow;
  font-size:28px;
  margin-bottom:300px;
}
```

You only need to include the files in your page head and body.

for the css use https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css and for the js use https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js

If you want to use local copies instead of remote ones, just paste the URL's in a browser and save the content in a file called aos.css and aos.js on you local webserver folder.

After that just include them on you page (css on the header and js at the end of the body and voila, you are ready to go. Add the elements with the desired transition and enjoy!